# How can i model groups of persons?

Tags: database, database-design, data-modeling

I need to model groups of persons and I can't find a way to design tabels to do it efficiently.

Groups can be thought as sets, unordered collections of one or more persons, each group should be uniquely identified by its components.

*Edit*: and a person can be part of more than one group.

My first attempt looks like this.
A table which contains all "persons" managed by the system.

```
table Persons(
  id int,
  name varchar,
  (other data...)
)
```

a table that contains groups and all group properties:

```
table Groups(
  group_id int,
  group_name varchar,
  (other data...)
)
```

and a table with the association between persons and groups

```
table gropus_persons (
  person_id int,
  group_id in
)
```

This design doesn't fit well with this requirements because it is hard to write the query to retrieve the group id from a list of components.

The only query I could come up to find the group composed by persons (1, 2, 3) looks like this:

```
select *
from groups g
where 
  g.group_id in (select group_id from gropus_persons where person_id = 1) 
  and g.group_id in (select group_id from gropus_persons where person_id = 2) 
  and g.group_id in (select group_id from gropus_persons where person_id = 3)
  and not exists (select 1 from gropus_persons where group_id = g.group_id and person_id not in (1,2,3))
```

the problem is that the number of components is variable so I can only use a dynamically generated query and add a subquery for each component each time I need to find a new group.

Is there a better solution?

Thank you in advice for the help!

Comment: Search about variations on relational division.

Comment: What if I told you that individuals and groups are really one in the same? (see The Party Model)

Comment: What if two groups are composed of the same people? Ie do you really want the group(s) if any with exactly those people? More generally, what are the restrictions on how people are organized into groups? Ie are there any constraints on groups_persons (other than, presumably, FKs to Persons and Groups)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to group by the "group" and count how many hits you receive. For this, you only need the intersection table:

```
select GroupID, count(*) as MemberCount
from   GroupsPersons
where  PersonID in( 1, 2, 3 )
group by GroupID
having count(*) = 3;
```

The problem comes with making this query suitable for a varying list of person id values. As you seem to already realize this will require dynamic SQL, the pseudo-code will look something like this:

```
stmt := 'select GroupID, count(*) as MemberCount '
     || 'from   GroupsPersons '
     || 'where  PersonID in( ' || CSVList || ' ) '
     || 'group by GroupID '
     || 'having count(*) = ' || length( CSVList );
```

The one potential bug you have to be wary of is if the same id repeats in the list. For example: `CSVList := '1, 2, 3, 2';`

This will generate a correct `count(*)` value of 3, but the `having` clause will be looking for 4.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to consider is to pivot/xpath the set of person IDs in alpha sequence and store it in your groups table and compare that string with your target.

For your example, you'd use `Select group_id from groups where personIDs = '1,2,3,'`

Comment: You could generate the comma-separated list of person IDs on the fly in the query, and leave the physical model alone; it would avoid any update anomalies caused by having the foreign keys *and* a physically stored list in the database. If group membership can change (i.e. people can join or leave a group over time), then this would be safer. I've done something very similar recently and it was pretty quick (used xml path in SQL Server).

Answer (score -1):

How about this, I think the schema is the same as yours, not sure:

```
create table Groups(
  group_id int primary key,
  group_name varchar(100)
);

create table Persons(
  person_id int primary key,
  name varchar
);


create table Membership(
  group_id int REFERENCES Groups (group_id),
  person_id int REFERENCES Persons (person_id)
);


INSERT INTO Persons 
VALUES (1, 'p1'), 
       (2, 'p2'), 
       (3, 'p2'), 
       (4, 'p2');

INSERT INTO Groups 
VALUES (1, 'group1'), 
       (2, 'group2'); 

INSERT INTO Membership 
VALUES (1, 1), 
       (1, 2), 
       (2, 2),
       (1, 3);
```

Then select:

```
select p.name, g.group_name
 from Persons as p 
 join Membership as m on p.person_id = m.person_id 
 join Groups as g on g.group_id = m.group_id 
 where m.group_id in (1, 2);
```

Obviously data would need to be adjusted to suit yours.